# Apk size increase when perform build apk operation in android

Tags: android, size, apk, android-instant-run

If instant run is active then i will test the app on my device using run command.then after install this app takes very less space on my device.But when i will build the apk and install this apk on a device. Then after installation it take very high space on my device. Can any one told me why this happing.